# Fazer contagem infinita dos números ordinais e expondo no documento HTML

Tags: javascript, contador, números

O que pretendo saber é como posso fazer um contador crescente em puro Javascript 0 , 1 , 2 , …

Quero algo automático, infinito sem que precise seta um número inteiro ou negativo

A contagem pode-se iniciar do 0 ou 1 em diante ...

## Exemplo

```
</script>

var min = 0    

var max = 9

for (var i = min; i < max; i++) {
  var seq = i/0;
  document.getElementById('num').innerHTML += i
}
<script>

<body>
   <span id='num'>&nbsp;</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Será algo como isto?

```js
const eleResult = document.getElementById('contador');
var n = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
  eleResult.innerHTML += n+ ' ';
  n++;
}, 100); // ajustas o tempo em milisegundos aqui
```

```html
<div id="contador"></div>
```

Para definir um máximo (neste caso 20) fazes:

```js
const eleResult = document.getElementById('contador');
var n = 0;
const max = 20;
const conta = window.setInterval(function() {
  eleResult.innerHTML += n+ ' ';
  if(n == max) window.clearInterval(conta);
  n++;
}, 100); // ajustas o tempo em milisegundos aqui
```

```html
<div id="contador"></div>
```

Comment: Isso sim, mas queria solto, sucessivamente 1 2 3 4 5 6  8 9 ... Teria como, reaproveitar esta sua rotina para deixar nos conforme?

Comment: Claro, vou editar @DiegoHenrique

Comment: Realmente ficou muito bom. Utilizou-se a palavra reservada [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), para atingir tal objetivo.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique isso usas se souberes que o valor da variável não vai mudar ao longo do programa, senão usa `var` . Neste caso funcionaria na mesma com `var`